# Переклад слова "Authority" в назвах організацій

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Судячи з назв статей в українській вікіпедії, немає сталого перекладу слова "authority" в значенні

> a person or organization having power or control in a particular, typically political or administrative, sphere.

Наприклад [Міжнародний орган з морського дна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%B7_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0), але [Палестинська національна адміністрація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F). Обидві назви очевидно просто перекладені з російської.

Чи є якийсь кращий варіант?

Comment: Authority  - (державний, національний або міжнародний) орган влади.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sup>[Англійсько-французько-німецько-український словник термінології Європейського Союзу 2007 (“Лабораторія наукового перекладу”)](https://e2u.org.ua/dicts/euro)</sup>
>
> **European Food Safety Authority (EFSA)**
>
> Європейський орган з безпечності харчових продуктів (ЄФСА; EFSA)
>
> ---
>
> **managing authority**
>
> орган управління *[допомогою]*
>
> ---
>
> **authority** *[див. також service; body; office; institution; agency]*
>
> орган [влади]
>
> ---
>
> **paying authority**
> платіжний орган

Загалом, **орган**, як на мене, цїлком підходе, бо воно в-одночас авторитетне і не обовязково керівне.

Трїба також зазначити, же тий приклад про Палестину *може* бути недорїчним, бо назву не змінити, оскільки вже затверџена за свойою лоґікою (цїлком можливо від СССР) і документово, наприклад [наше МЗС](https://mfa.gov.ua/embassies/palestina) називає йих саме так:

> Представництво України при Палестинській Національній Адміністрації (Відділення Посольства України в Державі Ізраїль при ПНА)

Декотрі взагалі перекладають як автономія:  *be* [аўтаномія](https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%9E%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F),  [автономия](https://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F),  [autonomie](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinsk%C3%A1_autonomie) ітд.

Якщо вдати ся до чистомовства, то тут буде шчось на зразок **самоуправи** або спросчено **влада** (*волода*), бо *авто* тут зазвичай то *влада* чи в тому дусі:

> from *auctor* "master, leader, author"

Приклади з гинших мов:  [самоуправа](https://mk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, що можна дати єдиний переклад на всі випадки життя.

- управа
- влада
- уряд
- регулятор
- бюро
- офіс
- упорядковувач
- наглядач
- адміністрація
- провід
- керівництво
- зверхність - *Під нівеляці́йною зве́рхністю моско́вською.* (Куліш)

Comment: Мені здається, автор запитання хотів, навпаки, знайти більш-менш «універсальний» варіант. (Але плюсанув, бо вважаю перелік «вузькоконтекстових» варіантів теж корисним. Хоча, звісно, було б краще з прикладами контекстів.)

Comment: ця відповідь зараз, як на мене, виглядає як погана словникова стаття. Погана - бо навіть немає розділення на ґрупи за значенням. Вона може бути помічна лише людині, які чітко знає, як шукати інформацію й обирати з-поміж наявної. Я би сказав, що це не додає нічого до інформації, яку можна знайти у словниках.

Comment: @Sasha ну, може *управа* і може бути таким замінником.

Comment: @P.Vowk, з одного боку — так. З іншого — це хоч щось, якийсь початковий поштовх. (Які я бачу шляхи покращення: додати приклади для кожного варіанта, зробити вікі-відповіддю, додати настанови щодо вибору.)